# Can we integrate a WinForms application with a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, interop

I want to integrate two existing applications into one. One of those apps is built on Windows Forms and the other on WPF.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various classes to help you with this.
For hosting Windows Forms controls in a WPF Window, you can use the [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) class. For hosting WPF Controls in a Windows Forms Window, you can use the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) class.

You can look here for mor information on the subject (windows forms section):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753178.aspx

Answer (score 4):

WPF supplies the [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) class that allows you to host WinForms controls inside a WPF window; conversely, WinForms supplies [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) that allows you to host WPF controls inside a form.

Unfortunately how well things work out is highly dependent on exactly what you are doing, last time I checked there were more than a few rough edges. For more information, definitely start from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx).

If you want to have "independent" WPF windows and WinForms forms inside the same application, you will *have* to make both frameworks "share" some code in your UI thread's message loop. For a primer on how to do that, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx).